# Poor sympy performance

Tags: python, floating-point, sympy

I'm using sympy 0.7.5 (installed via pip) with Python 3.4.2 on Windows 8.1 (x64). Please consider this short program:

```
import sympy
import time

start = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    sympy.Point(12345.0, 54321.0)
print('Elapsed (ms):', (time.time() - start) * 1000)
```

It takes my machine about **22 seconds** to execute this. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When generating `sympy.Point`s from floating point numbers they are automatically converted to rational numbers. This can be a good thing (e.g. if you would like to avoid floating point precision loss), but can also be very (*very*) slow. To disable conversion to `Rational`s pass `evaluate=False`, e.g.

```
%timeit sympy.Point(12345., 54321.)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.8 ms per loop 

%timeit sympy.Point(12345., 54321., evaluate = False)
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.3 us per loop
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I wonder why this has such a performance impact - converting to a rational is (in this case) trivially possible by chosing an appropriate base 10 denominator.

Indeed I would like to avoid precision loss. Could you possibly suggest another library that supports basic geometric calculations like computing polygon centroids and does not have performance issues like these?

Comment: I cannot comment why `Rational` is so much slower than the built-in types. Note that precision loss often isn't as bad as it sounds, the most obvious problem you could see is that equality is only approximate after computations.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on Point to convert your points to rational form via nsimplify, you can do so yourself by wrapping them in Rational. And then you take responsibility for making sure that you represented your float properly:

```
>>> Rational(.3)
5404319552844595/18014398509481984
>>> Rational('.3')  <--- smartest way to do so
3/10
>>> nsimplify(.3)   <--- slowest way to do so
3/10
```

(But floats that are ints should probably be handled as a special case.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to comment that the problem seems less important with Sympy Version: 1.0 (running with Python 3.5.1).
The following program gives only a factor two with "Evaluate = False" option :

```
start = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    Point(12345.0, 54321.0)
print('Elapsed (ms):', (time.time() - start) * 1000)

Elapsed (ms): 14.796018600463867

start = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    Point(12345.0, 54321.0, evaluate = False)
print('Elapsed (ms):', (time.time() - start) * 1000)

Elapsed (ms): 8.768081665039062
```